# At random times, random internet connections lag out indefinitely

Tags: router, internet, ethernet, latency

I have had this problem for 4 years and it has persisted through two households, two computers and two ISP's. The only constant thing has been my router which is why I have a hunch that it's the routers fault.

At completely random times, random internet connections will not load at all while others work perfectly fine. For example, I can access youtube and play videos with lightning speed, but twitter.com doesn't load. Other times it may be the opposite. Sometimes google doesn't load and twitter works perfectly. This problem persists for 4-5 minutes and closing the browser, refreshing the page etc doesn't do shit. And sometimes when I play mmorpgs and enter a new "instance", the chat in the game works but the world lags out. It's as if my router gets stuck on some packages but can deliver others.

What can this be caused by? Unfortunately I have lost admin password to my router and the reset button broke (lol) so I can't reset it. Is there a way to fix it without buying a new router, or do I have to? The internet connection is through a cable if it matters.

Comment: When you say "through a cable" do you mean coax cable? Also, do you have a separate modem or is it a modem/router combination unit? If you have separate modem and router, try plugging a PC directly into the modem and see if the problem persists or goes away. That will narrow it down to a PC/modem issue or a router issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this problem for 4 years and it has persisted through two households,
> two computers and two ISP's. The only constant thing has been my
> router which is why I have a hunch that it's the routers fault.

It is somewhat normal for consumer grade routers to need resetting from time to time. I have to do that with my own routers as well.

So I would suggest resetting the router but you cannot because there is no router Admin Password (forgotten) and in addition the hard reset button is broken.

So the practical solution here is to purchase a good router, set it up and document it so that you can reset it occasionally when needed.

That is what I would do myself.